# Programmatic fine-tune training in AWS

Tags: stable-diffusion, fine-tuning

I'm trying to setup an automatic fine tuning training pipeline with DreamBooth.  I've read this tutorial https://medium.com/@IAmxIAo/automating-fine-tuning-stable-diffusion-on-sagemaker-c340f65b24f2

However I don't understand what value does SageMaker add in this setup, vs plain EC2 / ECS?

Comment: Hello and welcome to GenAI Stack Exchange! Although external resources can provide useful information, we kindly request that all questions on this site be self-contained. Therefore, please include all pertinent details directly in the body of your question. Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

I've explored these options and now I understand the convenience SageMaker provides. It takes care of provisioning compatible instances, stops them when the job finishes or encounters an error, it also manages the training hyperparameters, uploads the completed model to S3.   All these can be done at lower level, but it makes sense to operate at a higher level until the cost become really significant.